How to use JWT token used obtained using MSAL library to commit code in Azure Repo
We are using @azure/msal-react node module to authenticate a user. User is prompted to enter his uid/pwd and Azure AD authenticates the user. Once, authenticated, user gets a JWT token.
This token is passed to Spring boot based rest API along with every request to our API server. Spring framework, authenticates the user using this token.
I now want to use this token to commit code in Azure GIT repo. I want to make restful calls from our Rest API to Azure Dev Ops API by passing this JWT token to commit the code.

What permission needs to be given to the user in order to perform this task & where do I need to set these permissions?
is it possible to use JWT token issued by Azure AD from one application to perform another task with another application ?


Hi @OpenStack, have you checked my answer below to ensure that the logged in user has corresponding permissions and configure API permissions for your app? Did it work for you?


What permission needs to be given to the user in order to perform this task & where do I need to set these permissions?

If you have followed this doc to register a single-page application (SPA) in the Microsoft identity platform, you can follow the steps below to assign permission to your SPA and use the access token to commit the code.

Add the SPA you created in Azure into Azure DevOps organization and assign it with Basic access level. Go to Organization Settings -> Users -> Add users.


Add the SPA into Contributors group of your target project. Go to your target project -> Project Settings -> Permissions -> Contributors -> Members -> Add your SPA.




is it possible to use JWT token issued by Azure AD from one application to perform another task with another application ?

I am afraid using this token for another application could lead to unauthorized access issues. It's suggested to issue a separate token for each application.

Update

You need to ensure that the logged in user meets the following prerequisites.


Have Basic access level or higher
Is a member of the Contributors security group or have the corresponding permissions set.


Configure API permissions for your app.
Go to API permissions -> Add a permission -> Azure DevOps.

Select vso.code_write -> Add permissions.




I want to clarify, I do not want to commit code using SPA credentials.  When i say I want to commit code using JWT, I am referring to JWT token issued to logged-in user. In this case JWT will have user info. Can I commit code using JWT token issued to user or do I need to use Personal access token (PAT ?

You need to ensure the logged in user has corresponding permissions in Azure DevOps and grant your app with vso.code_write API permission. See my update above.
